What does masu + そな mean?
In the song "World's End Dancehall" by wowaka, there is a line that goes:

パッとフラッと消えちゃいそな

I can, from what I know, translate this as (We) suddenly, by chance, completely disappear, but this leaves me with a few questions:
1: Why is the しまう in masu-stem form?
2: What does そな mean? It might just be a short version of そうな in order for the lyric to fit with the beat, but I'm not sure.
3: What does the masu stem of a verb + そな do?


This そな is a short, colloquial variant of そうな. This contraction is not very common, but it's used to make the phrase sound catchy or rhythmical.
そう has two completely different usages depending on whether the form of the previous verb is a dictionary form or a masu-stem.

Can stem+そう mean hearsay?
Can I use そうです (inference) in past?



So 消えちゃいそな is roughly the same as 消えてしまいそうな, which translates to "looking like it's about to disappear".
